# Segmentation fault when I change int to syscall/sysenter in assembly x86 (linux)

Tags: assembly, x86, system-calls

When I change the system call from `int $0x80` to `syscall` or `sysenter` in the following code:

```
mov $4, %rax
mov $1, %rbx
mov $String1, %rcx
mov $16, %rdx
int $0x80

#where String1 is defined sooner as String1: .asciz "String numero 1\n"
```

It gives me a segmentation fault. In GDB I got the message

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x00000000f7ffdbe9 in ?? ()

Since I'm not expert at all in assembly I don't know what is happening

**Edit**: the program is being built using `as` and `ld` with no special param

**Edit2**: I'm using x86_64 system, according to the output of `lshw | grep syscall` it returned:

> capacidades: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe **syscall** nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid dtherm arat cpufreq

But it didn't returned for `sysenter`...

On the comments, @Jester said that this different system calls implies in different registers being loaded for the parameters. Which registers are those then? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you on a 64 bit platform that supports sysenter?

Comment: Wasn't `sysenter` just used in the vsdo of 32-bit system? It is still used on 64-bit ones? Also note that the syscall n. 4 on 64-bit system is not *sys_write* but *sys_newstat*

Comment: Yeah, `SYSENTER` was introduced with the Pentium II processor, so it should be available on *most* 32-bit systems. The SEP flag can be used to check for it, after calling `CPUID`. (Although the Pentium Pro will lie to you and set SEP, even though `SYSENTER` is *not* available.) Windows XP introduced it as a "fast" way to make a system call, and uses it when it is available. Otherwise, it falls back to `int 2Eh`. Things are undoubtedly different on Linux; see [here](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/2894/8378).

Comment: The syscall interface uses a different calling convention, you need to load different registers in addition to using different syscall numbers as you have already been told.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer I'm using x86_64, accoding to the output of `lshw | grep syscall` on terminal I have support for syscall (but found no for sysenter). But the error occurs on both anyway..
@Jester which are those registers?

Comment: Ryan Chapman's blog is a good source of information related to syscall interface on x86-64 . http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem thanks to the comments.

First off, my architecture doesn't support sysenter. And to make the syscall I had to replace the code with:

```
mov $1, %rax
mov $1, %rdi
mov $String1, %rsi
mov $16, %rdx
syscall
```

and it worked just fine